# Is 3d look from contours possible in Blender using Grease Pencil?

Tags: texturing, normals, grease-pencil

I've recently started working with blender and was curious if it was possible to use the grease pencil tool in blender to achieve 3d look contouring as shown in these images. I've been trying various methods to try to achieve this but I just cannot come up with "b", where the cross-hatching provides concavity and convexity on the normal map. So I was wondering if I was just wasting my time or if this is possible in Blender using Grease Pencil at all.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know about doing this using grease pencil, but it's definitely possible using freestyle

Comment: Thank you!~ I'll check out the freestyle option and see if it can be used with grease pencil also.